# Could you please run the following code and suggest how to get rid of the error occurring? I'm running the code on cygwin

Tags: cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash/

lpd_factor=1
beam_radius=.01 
defocus=0
power=1000
weld_speed=1.5

while [ `echo "$beam_radius<=.05"|bc -l` == 1 ]
do
  lpd_factor=1 
  while [ `echo "$lpd_factor<=3"|bc -l` == 1 ]
  do
    defocus=0
    while [ `echo "$defocus==0"|bc -l` == 1 ]
    do
      power=1000
      while [ `echo "$power<=1400"|bc -l` == 1 ]
      do
        weld_speed=1.5
        while [ `echo "$weld_speed<=2.6"|bc -l` == 1 ]
        do
          echo "Beam Radius = $beam_radius"
          echo "LPD Factor = $lpd_factor"
          echo "Defocus = $defocus"
          echo "Power = $power"
          echo "Weld Speed = $weld_speed"
          cp input.txt.back input.txt
          python change.py $beam_radius $lpd_factor $defocus $power $weld_speed
          wine run.exe
          python parsing.py
          weld_speed=`echo "$weld_speed+0.1"|bc -l`
        done
        power=`echo "$power+40"|bc -l`
      done
      defocus=`echo "$defocus+0.1"|bc -l`
    done
    lpd_factor=`echo "$lpd_factor+1"|bc -l`
  done
  beam_radius=`echo "$beam_radius+0.01"|bc -l`
done
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: The shebang is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error here is that the shebang is wrong. It should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and not

```
#!/bin/bash/
```

which fails with:

```
./script.sh
bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash/: bad interpreter: Not a directory
```